# Remove-Item in powershell

Tags: powershell

[image: Apparently I can't post images yet, but this is an image about the error message]

The file still exists (because I can open it through powershell) but Remove-Item isn't able to find the location apparently. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Try to add `-Force`

Comment: If the file exists but has been marked as hidden, `-Force` would be required, as suggested by mhu. To unambiguously target a path as a _literal_ one, use `-LiteralPath` (without a parameter name, `Remove-Item`, like the other file-processing cmdlets, defaults to `-Path`, which expects _wildcard_ patterns - though that _shouldn't_ make a difference in this case). Thus, try `Remove-Item -Force -LiteralPath $PROFILE`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like like you hit a similar problem I recently ran into.  In my case I had a space at the end of a folder name, and Windows absolutely refused to delete it.

Turns out Windows has an alternate method for addressing files and folders where you have to prefix the path with `\\?\`.

In your case, probably need to try this:

```
Remove-Item "\\?\$Profile"
```

In my case I was working in the command prompt at the time and `RD /Q /S "\\?\FilePath"` worked.  So if worst comes to worst, you might do a `Write-Host $Profile`, select and copy the resulting path, switch to the command prompt and try the `RD /Q /S` command.

In your case, what is causing the problem is almost certainly the special characters after the `OneDrive\` in the path.

Comment: the special characters after OneDrive\ is 'documents' in Korean. Doing Remove-Item seems to work for the moment. Thank you for your help

Comment: @kimhanseo, glad it worked!  Thanks for letting me know that it means Documents in Korean.  From the video I just watched, looks like it might be an interesting language to learn.  But she listed off something like 20 vowels, that might be little hard to learn!  Have a good day!